# Spring MVC: Cannot convert value of type String to required type Category for property 'category'

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a class named Project that has an attribute category. The classes Project and Category have a one-to-many relationship.

```
public class Project {
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="category_id")
  private Category category;

public class Category {
  @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="category")
  private Set<Project> project = new HashSet<Project>(0);
```

In my JSP I have a dropdown where I select a category for a specific project

```
 <select class="form-control" name="category" >
   <c:forEach items="${categoriesList}" var="category">
   <option value="${category.id}"><c:out value="${category.category_name}" /></option>
   </c:forEach>
 </select>
```

And my controller looks like so

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/client/post_project", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String postProject(@ModelAttribute("project") Project p){
    projectService.addProject(p);
    return "/client/project";
}
```

I'm trying to add a project but I keep having this error. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
Field error in object 'project' on field 'category': rejected value [3]; 
codes [typeMismatch.project.category,typeMismatch.category,typeMismatch.model.Category,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [project.category,category]; arguments []; default message [category]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'model.Category' for property 'category'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [model.Category] for property 'category': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
```

Answer (score 4):

The idea is pretty straight forward. You will have to do 2 things.

1. You will have to create a class that implements `org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter<S, T>` where S (source) is the `java.lang.String` which you mentioned in your form.

> `<option value="${category.id}">`

and T (target) is the `Category`. The converter interface have one abstract method that you have to implement.

```
T convert(S source);
```

in the implementation you have to provide the logic to convert the source object into `Category`. It might be that you will need a bit help from your `@Repository` class.

2. After that you will have to register this converter in your WebMVC configuration class, that would be a class which most likely `extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport`. You will have to `@Override` the `addFormatters` methods and register your converter there.

So it would be something like

The converter class implementation

```
@Component
public Class StringToCategoryConverter implements Converter<String, Category> {

  @AutoWired
  private CategoryRepository repository;

  @Override
  public Category convert(final String source) {
    return repository.getCategoryById(source);
  }
}
```

The registration is also required and you do in the a class that normally extends `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`. Her går vi.

```
@Component
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

  @Override
  public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
       registry.addConverter(stringToCategoryConverter());
       super.addFormatters(registry);
  }

  @Bean 
  public StringToCategoryConverter stringToCategoryConverter(){
       return new StringToCategoryConverter();
  }
}
```

That it, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I've been struggling to achieve something similar for quite some time now, and this is the best comprimise I've seen.